# LibXML2 + pull parser (stax) : stream position (ftell) of the event ?

Tags: c, libxml2, seek, ftell

I'd like to create an index and later, access  some specific parts of a huge xml file, so I need to get the **offset** ( `ftell`  ... ) for some 'startElement' Events.

Using the pull parser (**stax**) interface of **libxml2** ( http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html ) is it possible to get the offset in the stream  of an event using **libxml2** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`xmlTextReaderByteConsumed`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html#xmlTextReaderByteConsumed):

> ```
> long xmlTextReaderByteConsumed (xmlTextReaderPtr reader)
> ```
>
> This function provides the current index of the parser used by the reader, relative to the start of the current entity. This function actually just wraps a call to xmlBytesConsumed() for the parser context associated with the reader. See xmlBytesConsumed() for more information.
>
> *reader:* an XML reader
> *Returns:*    the index in bytes from the beginning of the entity or -1 in case the index could not be computed.